# Click method does not work without the alert

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm writing some custom code with JS. I want to activate a section that is usually activated by pressing on the corresponding button.

The code I use is:

```
var controlEle = document.getElementById("header_notescontrol");
    if (controlEle.children != null && controlEle.children.length > 0) {
        var ctrl = controlEle.children[0];
        if (ctrl.title == "NOTES") {
            //alert(ctrl.title);
            ctrl.focus();
            ctrl.click();
        }
    }
```

But it does not work. If I uncomment the alert, after pressing on OK the code works.
Why is it so?

Comment: Perhaps some other element is being activated after this code fragment runs?

Comment: I tried with a timeout of three seconds, but it did not help. Jquery is allowed but that command does not work

Comment: What error you got in Console??

Comment: Object doesn't support property or method 'trigger'